# Poisson Regression with overload of zeroes SAS

Tags: poisson-distribution, model, count-data, sas, zero-inflation

I am testing different models for the best fit and most robust statistics to my data. My dataset contains over 50000 observations, approx. over 99.3% of the data are zeroes - such 0.7% are actual events.

Eventually see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDfPa.jpg

I search to find the best fit of the following models; Logistic, Poisson, NB, ZIP, ZINB, PLH, NBLH. (NB: Negative-binomial, ZI: Zero-Inflated, P: Poisson, LH: Logit Hurdle)

The first way I tried doing this was by estimating the binary response with logistic regression.

My questions: Can I use Poisson on the binary variable or should I instead impose the binary with some integer values? For instance with the associated loss; if y=1 then y_val=y*loss. In my case, the variance of y_val becomes approx. 2.5E9. I held to use the binary variable because it does not matter, in this purpose, what the company defaulted with, default is default no matter the amount.

Both with logistic regression and Poisson, I got some terrible statistic: Very high deviance value (and 0 p-value), terrible estimates (=many of the estimated parameters are 0 -> odds ratio =1), very low confidence intervals, everything seems to be 'wrong'. 
If I transform the response variable to log(y_val) for y>1 in Poisson the statistics seem to get better - however, this is against the assumptions of integer count response in Poisson.

I briefly have tested the ZINB, it does not change the statistics significantly (=it does not help at all in this case).

Does there exist any proper way of dealing with such a dataset? I am interested in achieving the best fit for my data (about startup business' and their default status).

The data are cleaned and ready to be fitted. Is there anything I should be aware of that I don't have mentioned?

I use the genmod procedure in SAS with dist=Poisson, zinb, zip etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your target variable is binary, Poisson, Negative Binomial, and their zero-inflated counterparts are not appropriate distributions, as you appear to have realized.   If you are using logistic regression with a target variable > 1, you aren't using logistic regression correctly (it appears from your paragraph starting "Both with logistic regression" that you may be doing so.)   It really isn't clear why you think "everything seems to be wrong" or why you think your parameter estimates are "terrible".  You should expand on those points to make your actual problem clearer.

Comment: @jbowman the histogram shows quite a range of integral valued responses. Not sure how a logit model was fit to the data. The story is hard to follow.

Comment: @AdamO - I suspect that histogram is of the y_val variable described in the second sentence of the paragraph headed by "My questions", not the binary variable described in the last sentence of the same paragraph.  But as you say, the story is hard to follow.

Comment: adamO: The plot shows as jbowman just mentioned, the y_val variable. 
I did not post the plot of the binary as I thought it was clear to say: y = 0 -> 99.3% and y = 1 -> 0.7% of total sample.
@jbowman: I was not clear apparently. Logistic regression are fitted for only the binary variable. The y_val are fitted for the other models. Hope it makes sense.
With terrible; I mean deviance value becomes 3700, thus value/DF approx. 0.07. The pearson chi-squared becomes 61400 and value/DF approx. 1.15.
AIC is fine I guess: 3680. If you want, I can link to the likelihood parameter estimates.

Answer (score 2):

1. No card-carrying statistician can make any recommendation about a modeling approach (generally a bivariate procedure) based on the univariate properties of the response. In fact, the issue is so complicated of finding the probability of the response given its unknown relationship to one or more regressors, the focus should mainly be on robust inferential procedures.
2. The frequent misuse of zero-inflated procedures requires wide-spread public awareness campaigns. Lots of zeroes $\ne$ zero-inflation. Zero-inflation is a mixture process, but several probability models can give you lots of zeroes.
3. You can't trust model fit statistics with such a large dataset. Every comparison is overpowered.
4. Zeroes are very much events in a Poisson probability model. If I am looking at automotive collision rates, do I exclude data from days where there were no accidents if I am an epidemiologist? You are quantitatively introducing a form of prevalent case bias.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out, as you say, that I can't find the probability of an event going default or not - and exactly as you mentioned I want to figure out the most robust procedure (in my text I called it "best fit" - sorry for not being clear)

Comment: Am I assuming wrong, with regard to your point 2? I consider the data zero-inflated as there is over 99% zeroes and under 1% of non-zeroes out of a sample of +54000. Correct me if I am wrong! :) 

But if my data had 100 observations with 80% zeros and the rest 20% was values between 1-3, then I would not call it zero inflated?

Comment: @Toni first you need to clearly state whether this is a probability problem or a statistics problem. If it's a probability problem, and you have 54,000 observations, why fit a probability distribution at all? You can just use the empirical distribution for all your estimates and forecasts. Your observations about the data are purely speculative: I can "make" a lot of zeros with arbitrarily high mean in a NB model setting $p$ and $r$ to very small values. There is no zero-inflation here.

Comment: It is a statistics problem. It does not make sense to predict an outcome in this situation I am at. 

Simplifying the question: How can I get the best fit (statistical) for my dataset, using different models?